# Query for OneToOne mapping is taking more than 8 seconds by using ms sql server

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using MS SQL server and jpa repository.

I want to join 2 tables and fetch top 20 columns, I have used Annotation in the Entity classes.

I am using findAll(Pageable) of Jpa Repository, its generating the query 10 times and taking 10 seconds, which is huge.

If i am searching the same in Db, its taking 277 ms.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Entity
@Table(name = "TVSource")
public class MyTelevisionSource {
    @Id
    private Long SourceId;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "nvarchar2 (2000)")
    private String LongName;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "nvarchar2 (2000)")
    private String DisplayName;

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "SourceId")
    private RCMSource rcmSource;  

}


@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Entity
@Table(name = "Source")
public class RCMSource {

    @Id
    private Long SourceId;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "nvarchar2 (2000)")
    private String SourceName;

}


@Service
public class TelevisionSourceService {

    @Autowired
    private TelevisionSourceRepository televisionSourceRepo;

    public List<MyTelevisionSource> getTelevisionSource(){

        Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(0, 10);
        Page<MyTelevisionSource> tvSource =  televisionSourceRepo.findAll(pageable);

        System.out.println(tvSource.getContent());

        return tvSource.getContent();
}


public interface TelevisionSourceRepository extends JpaRepository<MyTelevisionSource, Long> {

    Page<MyTelevisionSource> findAll(Pageable pageable);

}
```

I am using custom Query as below

@Query("select s.sourceid, s.sourceName from Source s inner join s.TelevisionSource t where t.sourceid = :sourceid")

```
Page<MyTelevisionSource> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

but its giving error, saying

Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Source is not mapped [SELECT  s.sourceid, s.sourceName, t.TvsourceLongName FROM Source as s INNER JOIN TelevisionSource as t ON s.sourceid = t.sourceid]

No Idea...why it is giving

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need lazyness (the `FetchType.LAZY` of your OneToOne annotation) ? Because of it, you have 1 main query that retrieve your television sources and then 10 queries to retrieve the RCMsources.
If you set `FetchType.EAGER` it should generate a single query with a left join

Comment: I tried the below also,

@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
 @JoinColumn(name = "SourceId")
 private RCMSource rcmSource;

But no change...now also its generating 11 queries as you said.

Do i am missing something?

Comment: I am using MS SQL server

Comment: I may have forgotten stg : add ```@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)``` on rcmSource field should force the join

Comment: I am using custom Query as below

@Query("select s.sourceid, s.sourceName from Source s inner join s.TelevisionSource t where t.sourceid = :sourceid")
 
 Page<MyTelevisionSource> findAll(Pageable pageable);

but its giving error, saying 

Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Source is not mapped [SELECT  s.sourceid, s.sourceName, t.TvsourceLongName FROM Source as s INNER JOIN TelevisionSource as t ON s.sourceid = t.sourceid]

No Idea...why it is giving

Comment: You are mixing different problems here. 
How can your findAll() method with no other parameters than pageable execute a query with a :sourceid parameter ???
And in HQL/Queries you must use the entities name, not the tables name, so RCMSource and not Source

Comment: I want to join both the tables and i want to get top 10 records.

Page<T> findAll(Pageable pageable);

I want to use this signature of findAll method.

If you can propose something else.

Comment: @Query("select t.TvsourceLongName from MyTelevisionSource t inner join RCMSource s where s.sourceid = t.sourceid")

this query is fine...am i right?

Comment: Yes I guess it is the only way. Actually the Fetch(JOIN) annotation is not considered when using JPA on top of Hibernate. However you can do ```select t from  MyTelevisionSource t inner join RCMSource s where s.sourceid = t.sourceid``` to get the full entity and not only the name